# Passing a var that is not being implemented by the form

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following code that checks the `userName` & `userPassword` is correct then login but I also want to include another couple checks that are not on the login form but come from the database - `userGroup - user/admin` & `userActive - yes/no`.  How would I write the login function to take in the vars?

**Controller:**

```
public function login()
{
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('userName','userName', 'required|valid_email|trim|max_length[99]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('userPassword','userPassword', 'required|trim|max_length[200]|xss_clean|callback__checkUser');

        if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) {
        // set CLEAN data in the session.
            redirect('admin/dashboard');
        }

        $this->index();
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
function _checkUser(){ // Private function 
        extract($_POST);

        $login = $this->admin_model->check_login($userName,$userPassword,$userGroup,$userEmail,$userActive);

        if(! $login){

        $this->session->set_flashdata('login_error', TRUE); 
        $this->form_validation->set_message('_checkUser','Sorry your %s is not correct');

        return FALSE;

    }else{
        $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', TRUE);
        $this->session->set_userdata('userID', $user->id);
        $this->session->set_userdata('userName',$user->userName);
        $this->session->set_userdata('firstName',$user->userFirstName);
        $this->session->set_userdata('lastName'),$user->userLastName;
        $this->session->set_userdata('userEmail',$user->userEmail);
        $this->session->set_userdata('userGroup'),$user->userGroup;
        $this->session->set_userdata('userActive'),$user->userActive;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question properly you can something like this in your else part

```
 // Your current else part
 else{
    $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', TRUE);
    $this->session->set_userdata('userID', $user->id);
    $this->session->set_userdata('userName',$user->userName);
    $this->session->set_userdata('firstName',$user->userFirstName);
    $this->session->set_userdata('lastName'),$user->userLastName;
    $this->session->set_userdata('userEmail',$user->userEmail);
    $this->session->set_userdata('userGroup'),$user->userGroup;
    $this->session->set_userdata('userActive'),$user->userActive;
}
```

you can have something like this

```
else{
    if($user->userGourp == "Admin" && $user->userActive == "Yes"){
    $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', TRUE);
    $this->session->set_userdata('userID', $user->id);
    $this->session->set_userdata('userName',$user->userName);
    $this->session->set_userdata('firstName',$user->userFirstName);
    $this->session->set_userdata('lastName'),$user->userLastName;
    $this->session->set_userdata('userEmail',$user->userEmail);
    $this->session->set_userdata('userGroup'),$user->userGroup;
    $this->session->set_userdata('userActive'),$user->userActive;
   }
   else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('login_error', TRUE); 
       $this->form_validation->set_message('_checkUser','Sorry your %s is not correct');          
       return FALSE;
   }
}
```

Comment: Jaspreet,  what would be above the first else{?